# Using Invoke-Command, inside the script the methods and properties are not working

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a file that contains records with the name of a server and the name of its sqlserver instance. I want to read for each record the jobs configured and their status for the last run.

I setup a credential, then define the script to gather information and finally calls Invoke-Command. My problem is that where I expect to find the gathered information I'm just getting the name of properties.

This is my script:

```
$a = Get-Credential

$scriptBlock={ 
  param($server,$instance) $OFS=","

  import-module sqlps
  SQLSERVER:
  cd SQL\$server\$instance\JobServer\Jobs
  foreach($CurJob in (ls)){
    write-output "$CurJob.DisplayName`n    Last Run: $CurJob.LastRunDate`n    Ultima Last Run Otcome:$CurJob.LastRunOutcome`n    Next Run: $CurJob.NextRunDate"
  }
}

Import-Csv -Header Server, Instance -Delimiter "|" .\servers_with_jobs.txt | %{
  write-output "Inovoking with server: $_.Server/$_.Instance"

  $JobNumber=Invoke-Command -AsJob -ComputerName $_.Server -Credential $a -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $_.Server, $_.Instance

  Wait-Job $JobNumber

  $JobResult = Receive-Job $JobNumber
  $JobResult
}
```

And when I run, then I get the following:

```
Inovoking with server: @{Server=server01.company.net; Instance=INST1}.Server/@{Server=server01.company.net; Instance=INST1}.Instance

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
148    Job148          RemoteJob       Completed     True            server01.e...  ...
WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'sqlps' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands with
unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
ReplicationJob1.DisplayName
    Last Run: ReplicationJob1.LastRunDate
    Ultima Last Run Otcome:ReplicationJob1.LastRunOutcome
    Next Run: ReplicationJob1.NextRunDate
ReplicationJob2.DisplayName
    Last Run: ReplicationJob2.LastRunDate
    Ultima Last Run Otcome:ReplicationJob2.LastRunOutcome
    Next Run: ReplicationJob2.NextRunDate
```

It seems like if the script resolve the name of the job as the ToString method. Even I try to print the type for the $CurJob object but instead it show something like the output of running Get-Member:

```
PSComputerName            : server01.company.net
RunspaceId                : 547127ac-ae58-4144-b769-507c6cf18b2e
Module                    : Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
Assembly                  : Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
TypeHandle                : System.RuntimeTypeHandle
BaseType                  : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.AgentObjectBase
UnderlyingSystemType      : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.Job
FullName                  : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.Job
AssemblyQualifiedName     : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.Job, Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
Namespace                 : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent
GUID                      : c556994c-df26-35b1-8b70-78bce85a3e25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate parameter calls inside a string evaluation.  I didn't test this but I think the example will do the trick.

### Example

```ps1
$a = Get-Credential

$scriptBlock={ 
  param($server,$instance) $OFS=","

  import-module sqlps
  SQLSERVER:
  cd SQL\$server\$instance\JobServer\Jobs
  foreach($CurJob in (ls)){
    write-output "$($CurJob.DisplayName)`n    Last Run: $($CurJob.LastRunDate)`n    Ultima Last Run Otcome:$($CurJob.LastRunOutcome)`n    Next Run: $($CurJob.NextRunDate)"
  }
}

Import-Csv -Header Server, Instance -Delimiter "|" .\servers_with_jobs.txt | %{
  write-output "Inovoking with server: $($_.Server)/$($_.Instance)"

  $JobNumber=Invoke-Command -AsJob -ComputerName $_.Server -Credential $a -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $_.Server, $_.Instance

  Wait-Job $JobNumber

  $JobResult = Receive-Job $JobNumber
  $JobResult
}
```

## A Better Way

Instead of using string evaluations use `-f` to format a string.

### Example

```
'Inovoking with server: {0}/{1}' -f $_.Server, $_.Instance
```